# Access denied when creating Time Trigger Windows task under Administrator account

Tags: c++, windows-task-scheduler

I built a testing program (without changing any code) using the "Time Trigger Example (C++)" code that Microsoft provides.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/time-trigger-example--c---

The program runs properly under any Administrator account or Standard account that I created for testing purposes like "userAdmin" and "testAcct", but the program fails when I run the program under the account with the exact user name "Administrator". I have to choose *Run as administrator* to make it work properly, which is very weird to me.

```cpp
#include "windows.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include "cstdio"
#include "cstring"Run as administrator" to make it work properly, which is VERY weird to me. Please help :(

#include "windows.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include "cstdio"
#include "cstring"
#include "atlbase.h"
#include "comdef.h"
#include "wincred.h"
#include "taskschd.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "taskschd.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "comsupp.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "credui.lib")

#pragma warning(disable:4996)

using namespace std;

int __cdecl wmain()
{
    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Initialize COM.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCoInitializeEx failed: %x", hr);
        return 1;
    }

    //  Set general COM security levels.
    hr = CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL,Run as administrator" to make it work properly, which is VERY weird to me. Please help :(

#include "windows.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include "cstdio"
#include "cstring"
#include "atlbase.h"
#include "comdef.h"
#include "wincred.h"
#include "taskschd.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "taskschd.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "comsupp.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "credui.lib")

#pragma warning(disable:4996)

using namespace std;

int __cdecl wmain()
{
    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Initialize COM.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCoInitializeEx failed: %x", hr);
        return 1;
    }

    //  Set general COM security levels.
    hr = CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL,
        -1,
        NULL,
        -1,
        NULL,
#include "atlbase.h"
#include "comdef.h"
#include "wincred.h"
#include "taskschd.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "taskschd.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "comsupp.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "credui.lib")

#pragma warning(disable:4996)

using namespace std;

int __cdecl wmain()
{
    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Initialize COM.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCoInitializeEx failed: %x", hr);
        return 1;
    }

    //  Set general COM security levels.
    hr = CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL,
        -1,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY,
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCoInitializeSecurity failed: %x", hr);
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Create a name for the task.
    LPCWSTR wszTaskName = L"__Time Trigger Test Task__";

    //  Get the windows directory and set the path to notepad.exe.
    wstring wstrExecutablePath = _wgetenv(L"WINDIR");
    wstrExecutablePath += L"\\SYSTEM32\\NOTEPAD.EXE";


    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Create an instance of the Task Service. 
    ITaskService *pService = NULL;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskScheduler,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_ITaskService,
        (void**)&pService);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Failed to create an instance of ITaskService: %x", hr);
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  Connect to the task service.
    hr = pService->Connect(_variant_t(), _variant_t(),
        _variant_t(), _variant_t());
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("ITaskService::Connect failed: %x", hr);
        pService->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Get the pointer to the root task folder.  This folder will hold the
    //  new task that is registered.
    ITaskFolder *pRootFolder = NULL;
    hr = pService->GetFolder(_bstr_t(L"\\"), &pRootFolder);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Cannot get Root folder pointer: %x", hr);
        pService->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  If the same task exists, remove it.
    pRootFolder->DeleteTask(_bstr_t(wszTaskName), 0);

    //  Create the task definition object to create the task.
    ITaskDefinition *pTask = NULL;
    hr = pService->NewTask(0, &pTask);

    pService->Release();  // COM clean up.  Pointer is no longer used.
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Failed to CoCreate an instance of the TaskService class: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Get the registration info for setting the identification.
    IRegistrationInfo *pRegInfo = NULL;
    hr = pTask->get_RegistrationInfo(&pRegInfo);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot get identification pointer: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    hr = pRegInfo->put_Author(CComBSTR(L"Author Name"));
    pRegInfo->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot put identification info: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Create the principal for the task - these credentials
    //  are overwritten with the credentials passed to RegisterTaskDefinition
    IPrincipal *pPrincipal = NULL;
    hr = pTask->get_Principal(&pPrincipal);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot get principal pointer: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  Set up principal logon type to interactive logon
    hr = pPrincipal->put_LogonType(TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN);
    pPrincipal->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot put principal info: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Create the settings for the task
    ITaskSettings *pSettings = NULL;
    hr = pTask->get_Settings(&pSettings);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot get settings pointer: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  Set setting values for the task.  
    hr = pSettings->put_StartWhenAvailable(VARIANT_TRUE);
    pSettings->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot put setting information: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    // Set the idle settings for the task.
    IIdleSettings *pIdleSettings = NULL;
    hr = pSettings->get_IdleSettings(&pIdleSettings);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot get idle setting information: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    hr = pIdleSettings->put_WaitTimeout(CComBSTR(L"PT5M"));
    pIdleSettings->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot put idle setting information: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }


    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Get the trigger collection to insert the time trigger.
    ITriggerCollection *pTriggerCollection = NULL;
    hr = pTask->get_Triggers(&pTriggerCollection);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot get trigger collection: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  Add the time trigger to the task.
    ITrigger *pTrigger = NULL;
    hr = pTriggerCollection->Create(TASK_TRIGGER_TIME, &pTrigger);
    pTriggerCollection->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot create trigger: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    ITimeTrigger *pTimeTrigger = NULL;
    hr = pTrigger->QueryInterface(
        IID_ITimeTrigger, (void**)&pTimeTrigger);
    pTrigger->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nQueryInterface call failed for ITimeTrigger: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    hr = pTimeTrigger->put_Id(_bstr_t(L"Trigger1"));
    if (FAILED(hr))
        printf("\nCannot put trigger ID: %x", hr);

    hr = pTimeTrigger->put_EndBoundary(_bstr_t(L"2015-05-02T08:00:00"));
    if (FAILED(hr))
        printf("\nCannot put end boundary on trigger: %x", hr);

    //  Set the task to start at a certain time. The time 
    //  format should be YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS(+-)(timezone).
    //  For example, the start boundary below
    //  is January 1st 2005 at 12:05
    hr = pTimeTrigger->put_StartBoundary(_bstr_t(L"2005-01-01T12:05:00"));
    pTimeTrigger->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot add start boundary to trigger: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }


    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Add an action to the task. This task will execute notepad.exe.     
    IActionCollection *pActionCollection = NULL;

    //  Get the task action collection pointer.
    hr = pTask->get_Actions(&pActionCollection);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot get Task collection pointer: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  Create the action, specifying that it is an executable action.
    IAction *pAction = NULL;
    hr = pActionCollection->Create(TASK_ACTION_EXEC, &pAction);
    pActionCollection->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot create the action: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    IExecAction *pExecAction = NULL;
    //  QI for the executable task pointer.
    hr = pAction->QueryInterface(
        IID_IExecAction, (void**)&pExecAction);
    pAction->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nQueryInterface call failed for IExecAction: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  Set the path of the executable to notepad.exe.
    hr = pExecAction->put_Path(_bstr_t(wstrExecutablePath.c_str()));
    pExecAction->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot put action path: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Save the task in the root folder.
    IRegisteredTask *pRegisteredTask = NULL;
    hr = pRootFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition(
        _bstr_t(wszTaskName),
        pTask,
        TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE,
        _variant_t(),
        _variant_t(),
        TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN,
        _variant_t(L""),
        &pRegisteredTask);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nError saving the Task : %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\n Success! Task successfully registered. ");

    //  Clean up.
    pRootFolder->Release();
    pTask->Release();
    pRegisteredTask->Release();
    CoUninitialize();

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds to me as if your Administrator account is not an administrator.

Comment: Your question does not seem to be a programming question, and thus is off-topic for Stack Overflow. That said, the default on Windows these days is for the account named "Administrator" to be disabled. In fact, I think in Windows 10 you cannot even enable that account any more, so it would not be surprising to find that it can't be used to run tasks under Task Scheduler.